# WSO2 WSF/PHP server with visual foxpro client

Tags: php, web-services, wso2, foxpro, wsh

I’m using WSO2 WSF/PHP (wamp) and I'm trying to consume the sample web service (echo_service.php) from a foxpro client.
I have tried this code with no success:

```
TEXT TO requestPayloadString NOSHOW
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <ns1:echoString xmlns:ns1="http://wso2.org/wsfphp/samples">
         <text>Hello World!</text>
     </ns1:echoString>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
ENDTEXT

LOCAL httpRequest
httpRequest = CREATEOBJECT("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

httpRequest.Open("GET", "http://192.168.56.101/samples/echo_service.php", .F.)
httpRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
httpRequest.SetRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://wso2.org/wsfphp/samples/echoString")
httpRequest.Send(requestPayloadString)

? httpRequest.ResponseText 
? TRANSFORM( httpRequest.Status )
? TRANSFORM( httpRequest.StatusText )
```

The above returns the service description (Deployed Services samples_echo_service.php Available Operations echoString) with `status = 200` and `statustext = OK`.

With `POST` I get

```
Transport identified SOAP version does not match with SOAP message version
status=500 statustext=Internal Server Error
```

The next code return an `OLE error` (`Error 1429`):

```
SoapMapper:Restoring data into SoapMapper returnVal failed HRESULT=0x80070057:
The parameter is incorrect.
   - Client:Unspecified client error. HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.

lcWSDL = "http://192.168.56.101/samples/echo_service.php?wsdl"
loSoap = Createobject("mssoap.soapclient30")
loSoap.MSSoapInit(lcWSDL)
loSoap.echoString("hello")
```

The client samples in php are working ok.
The code works with other webservices (tried http://webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx)

Need any help to solve this problem.

Also, if consuming web service from WSO2 WSF/PHP in too complicated, any PHP alternatives that works with Visual Foxpro?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing and comparing the headers send by foxpro and working php client the only difference was this:

```
httpRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8")
```

Replacing the content-type resolved the issue, but I'm still unable to use soapclient...